# Visual Studio 2010 - fix "using" feature?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to fix "using" in my C# file?
I looking for some sort of "fix (organize) imports" from NetBeans or Eclise for java. 
I looking for the easiest way to fix issue: "The type or namespace could not be found" when I miss some "using" directive. Actually, I do not remember all C# classes hierarchy.

Answer (score 9):

When you type the name of a type which isn't already imported, it will be highlighted in red. If you press Ctrl-period, Visual Studio will offer to import it. (There should be a blue dot near the cursor to indicate this as a possibility.) Or using ReSharper, press Alt-Enter on the line with the problem.

Note that that only tackles the "adding a using directive" side of things. There's also the "Remove and sort using directives" command for keeping things tidy. I typically having that bound to Ctrl-Shift-U, but I don't *think* it has a shortcut by default.

Comment: But does it mean, there is no way to add all the appropriate using directives (asking the user to choose if there is ambiguity) for the whole file at once? I cannot find it.

Comment: @Jirka-x1: I'm not aware of one, no. Resharper *may* have something along those lines. I usually find it's fine to just fill them in as I go.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the necessary assemblies referenced, you can right click (or hover) on an unrecognized class name to find a "Resolve" submenu to help you. You can find options to add necessary usings or change the class name to fully qualified with namespaces in your code.